# Mercurial like method for creating git remote repository

Tags: linux, git, mercurial

When I was using Mercurial, creating a remote repository is one command line:

```
hg clone local remote
```

Where remote is something accessible via ssh.  For instance:

```
hg clone /path/to/local/repo.hg ssh://host.name/path/to/new/clone.hg
```

I don't know if it is a functionality in Mercurial or we have installed something to make that possible.

Is there any way to do that with git? Or install something that will allow me to do the same like with Mercurial?

**NOTE**

My question is not 'How to clone a remote repository?'

Comment: The command you prompt is for git

Comment: @ciccioska Thanks I fixed it.

Comment: From [this manual page](https://selenic.com/hg/help/clone) I cannot see how would you go about having `remote` actually be something accessible "remotely" -- as via SSH or HTTP or whatever; all examples have local directory as their `remote`. So could you provide a real example of your past usage?

Comment: If you really just failed to provide a good wording for the question "how do I locally clone a Git repo?" then the answer would be `git clone remote local` as in `git clone /path/to/existing/repo /path/to/new/repo`.

Comment: @kostix I don't understand your first comment? What I want is to clone my repository in another machine (accessible via ssh) and others can clone it (if they have the rights)

Comment: Uh, well, I don't understand what you did not understand ;-) Let's rephrase: 1) you have a local repository. 2) You want to know how would you make a clone of this repository available on another computer accessible via SSH. Is that correct?

Comment: @kostix Yes that's what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that with a single command, and you can't do that using Git alone either.

You roll something like this:

1. Initialize a repository on the server:

   ```
   ssh user@server git init --bare /path/to/the/new/repo
   ```
2. Push your local repository there:

   ```
   git push --all --tags ssh://user@server/path/to/the/new/repo
   ```

If you intend to work with that new remote repository (push/fetch) afterwards, it makes sense to add it as a named remote, so your step #2 becomes:

```
git remote add foo ssh://user@server/path/to/the/new/repo
git push --all --tags foo
```